# Can I point cursor to a character on bash CLI prompt using mouse?

Tags: bash, command-line, mouse, cursor

How can I point my cursor to a character on bash CLI prompt using mouse?
Example: `user@host:$ grep abcd /tmp/dir1/dir2/dir3/ *.c | grep st1` In this example the command is lengthy and if I want to change the string `abcd` to `abcde` I will have to use my keyboard arrows to bring my cursor to that `abcd` string. If I could use my mouse to directly point to the string , it would ease my job.

Comment: Related: [Any terminal shell with mouse support?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444601/108618)

Comment: You could also give `^abcd^abcde` after running the first command a shot.